# SASS/SCSS Functions Compile as Literal Output

Tags: css, sass

Consider the following SCSS code:

```scss
div {
    background-color: tint(#FF0000, 10%);
}
```

Produces the following CSS output:

```css
div {
  background-color: tint(#FF0000, 10%); }
```

**Why is the `tint` function not being calculated and replaced with the actual value?**

Note: I assumed they were built-in functions.

I can't find any documentation that would suggest how those functions should be referenced.

I was following this: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions

Comment: where is the tint function definition?

Comment: @doğukan I assumed they were built-in functions. I can't find any documentation that would suggest how those functions should be referenced. I was following this: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions

Comment: `Both of these are accessible in Bourbon.` they are not built-in functions. you should define. you can find the example here https://codepen.io/teyepe/pen/MmdLBj

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/main/core/bourbon/library/_tint.scss

Comment: If you need to use tint and shade, you can go to Bourbon site and copy the functions from there into your scss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blog post is outdated. `tint` and `shade` are just mixins (in Compass or some libraries like it), wrapping the built-in `mix` function:

```
mix(white, $color, $percentage);
```

and

```
mix(black, $color, $percentage);
```

Comment: No need for 3rd party libs...love it! :)